# Dohop flight search page, Facebook share not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, share

I created whitelable in Dohop flight search site. Then i link it to my website. When i share flight result with facebook, it display error: 'An error occurred. Please try later'. Help me to set facebook configuration in Dohop site for sharing.

This is my page:

http://flightsearch.onlinetravelfair.com/?d1=260116&d2=020216&a1=KUL&a2=IND&return=1

I am creating whiteLabel with CNAME.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: i get this error from facebook debug:

fb:app_id hasn't been included in the meta tags. Specify the app ID so that stories shared to Facebook will be properly attributed to the app. Alternatively, app_id can be set in url when open the share dialog. Otherwise, the default app id( 966242223397117 ) will be assigned.

Comment: Sharing works fine; however, the debug tool shows other warnings as well, about missing `og` meta tags – if you want to be in control over what image Facebook uses and what description, you should specify those as well.